# Why does my Falcon script print the date a month ahead instead of today's date?

Tags: date, falcon

Today is April 25, 2009 which in US format is abbreviated month-day-year, so today is 04-25-09. This line

```
> CurrentTime().toString("%m-%d-%y")
```

should print "04-25-09". Instead it prints "05-25-09". Why is that? According to the [docs](http://www.falconpl.org/project_docs/core/_functions.html#CurrentTime) `CurrentTime()` returns a `TimeStamp` instance. `TimeStamp` has a `toString()` method which accepts a date/time format as a parameter, which is supposed to be in 
[strftime format](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). Is there something wrong with my understanding of the code? I am using Falcon 0.8.14.2("Vulture") on Windows Vista (64-bit)

[2](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime): http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime strftime format

Comment: What does it return if you don't pass a format parameter to the toString() method?  Maybe the problem is with your format string -- could 05 be minutes?

Comment: @Jonathan - Without any formatting I get "2009-04-25 22:32:06.262" or similar, depending on the time, and with formatting I still get "05-25-09".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also posted this question on the Falcon [Google Group](http://groups.google.it/group/falconpl/browse_thread/thread/21525a601a90de4d). Apparently, this is an issue with Falcon itself and is fixed in version 0.9.1. Version 0.9.1 will be officially released in a week or two according to the response I received from Giancarlo Niccolai, the inventor of the Falcon programming language.

Comment: I have confirmed that the newer version does, indeed, fix this issue.